# How to display clicked listview item in another activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onitemclicklistener

I have a challenge with setOnItemClickListener method to display appropriate listItem in another activity. I do this with a Firebase. I have 3  variables(String): Name,Phone,Email

Snippet of my code in **MainActivity:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ChatMessage selectedList = adapter.getItem(position);
                if(selectedList != null) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainDetails.class);
                    long listId = adapter.getItemId(position);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_ID, listId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**KEY_LIST_ID** in Constants.class:

```
public static final String KEY_LIST_ID = "LIST_ID";
```

This KEY_LIST_ID is needed to save each itemId?

**ChatAdapter:**

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage> {

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);

    }

    @Override
    public ChatMessage getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;


        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_username);
            viewHolder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_message);
            viewHolder.email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_email);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ChatMessage item = getItem(position);
        if(item != null) {
            viewHolder.username.setText(item.getName());
            viewHolder.message.setText(item.getPhone());
            viewHolder.email.setText(item.getEmail());
        }

        return convertView;
    }




    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView username;
        TextView message;
        TextView email;
    }
}
```

**MainDetails:** Activity which should display appropriate listItem:

```
private TextView detailsName, detailsPhone, detailsEmail;
    private ChatMessage chatMessage;
    private ListView listView;
    private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    private String listId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_details);

        detailsName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsName);
        detailsPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsText);
        detailsEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detsEmail);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        listId = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_ID);



    }
```

Now, it shows nothing in MainDetails.

Could somebody help me how to display every each ListItem in this Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put listId as `long`. So use:

`long listId = intent.getLongExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_ID, -1L);`

**EDIT:**
To get user name, phone and email:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ChatMessage selectedList = adapter.getItem(position);
                if(selectedList != null) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainDetails.class);
                   // long listId = adapter.getItemId(position);

                        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_NAME, selectedList.getName());
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_PHONE, selectedList.getPhone());
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_EMAIL, selectedList.getEmail());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
            }
        });
```

**in MainDetails**

```
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        name= intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_NAME);
        phone= intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_PHONE);
        email= intent.getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LIST_EMAIL);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. do u get null listId? or null selectedList? did u try to print listId if it is null?

Comment: I changed listId, as you said, to long in MainDetails. But it didn't help to resolve problem. In this MainDetails Activity I would like to display particulary name, email and phone from listView.

Comment: you are starting new activity. so listview not accessible from MainDetailActivity directly. Better you pass name phone email arguments to the intent instead of listId.

Comment: Could you tell me how and where I can do this?